# $L_1$ norm concentration of an empirical distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

Suppose we have one random variable $X$, whose sample space is $\mathbb{X}=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$, and the size of the sample space is $m$. We have $N$ i.i.d. samples from this distribution, and $x_i$ occurs $N_i$ times out of $N$ samples. Then we construct such empirical distribution as $\hat{P}(X=x_i)=\frac{N_i}{N}$.

The question is the concentration bounds of $L_1$ norm of the distribution estimate error. That is to say, we have a "good event" -- the estimation error is small with a high probability, i.e., $\mathbb{P}\{\sum_{x_i\in\mathbb{X}}|\hat{P}(X=x_i)-P(X=x_i)| \leq t\} \geq 1-\delta$, where $\delta$ is a small value, and the question is what is $t$ ?

Comment: do you mean $x_i$ occurs $N_i$ times out of $N$ samples of $X$?

Comment: Exactly. @kodlu

Comment: The latter sum is a random variable. What kind of bound on it, and in what specific sense, do you want?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I mean concentration bound, for example like Hoeffding inequality for one-dimensional variable. Here, we want $\mathbb{P}\{\sum_{x_i\in\mathbb{X}}|\hat{P}(X=x_i)-P(X=x_i)| \leq t\} \geq 1-\delta$, where $\delta$ is a small value, and the question is what is $t$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The way this is usually put, the answer is that to achieve $\Pr[\|\hat{P}-P\|_1 \leq t] \geq 1- \delta$, one needs a sample size $N = \Theta\left(\frac{m + \ln(1/\delta)}{t^2}\right)$.

The answer is the same up to constant factors for $L_1$ distance and total variation distance, as the first always equals twice the second.

Find a proof and discussion by Clement Canonne here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/39030/8243